# Trying to read excel file from Spark (crealytics) but can't see data

Tags: excel, scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

1) I am trying to read first excel file using

```
val df1 = spark.read.excel(
   dataAddress = dataAdd,
   header = true,
**maxRowsInMemory = 5)**
  .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", "true")
  .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load(dataFilePath)
```

with enabled maxRowInMemory, so it doesn't give data but it only shows Schema.

But, If I removed maxRowInMemory I get data.

2)  But with another excel file if I remove maxRowInMemory, I am getting Cannot Convert String to Numeric Cell.....

Can anyone please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, check may it works for you,

```
val df1 = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
                    .option("useHeader", "true") \                
                    .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true") \  
                    .option("inferSchema", "true") \              
                    .option("addColorColumns", "False") \         
                    .option("maxRowsInMey", 2000) \               
                    .option("sheetName", "Import") \              
                    .load(dataFilePath)
```

Check the `com.crealytics` library verion, The new version of `com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.11:0.12.5` library works with non string column/header names as well.

Comment: thanks for response. But I am getting ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC cell for other file

Comment: This is due to you have numeric value in header field. If you put string value then it works. also could you post your crealytics library version in spark?

Comment: I can't change anything in the file. crealytics version-com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.11:0.13.1

Comment: i  am using 0.13.1 I think this one is latest one but i will check with 0.12.5

Comment: no its not working with 0.12.5 also. Is there any other option?

Comment: Ohh sorry man, not sure, how to fix this? May need to spend some time on this.